# Crosschain between Hyperledger Fabric and Ethereum?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ethereum

Is there any project focusing on crosschain between Hyperledger Fabric and Ethereum? Or any way to achieve that?

Comment: Would you please check the following link:  https://www.hyperledger.org/blog/2018/10/26/hyperledger-fabric-now-supports-ethereum

Comment: This one seems a migration of EVM which enables developers do not need to rewrite smart contracts in other languages, not the crosschain solution that I mean.